# Obexctl doesnot take any input

Tags: bluez, imx6, obex

When I run **obexctl** an interactive obex will get created. But I am not able to write anything into it.
If I press Ctrl+c then it returns,

````
[obex]# 
dbus[3097]: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection != NULL" failed in file ../../dbus-1.12.2/dbus/dbus-connection..
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.

  D-Bus not built with -rdynamic so unable to print a backtrace
Aborted (core dumped)```
````

Comment: Thanking in advance

Answer (score -1):

At first run `systemctl --user start obex`.
Then run `obexctl`.
Now you can write a command in `[obex]#`